# Having issues updating charts in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to create AppsScript code which will update a chart's Minimum and Maximum values on the Vertical Axis to encompass only the values actually within the chart's data.

Unfortunately, despite any and all troubleshooting I do, the code always fails at "sheet.updateChart(newChart);" with the error "Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id [Sheet ID]"

How can I fix this?

Here is the specific code I'm working with below:

```
function adjustChartBounds() {
  var sheetName = "Report";
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();

  if (charts.length > 0) {
    var chart = charts[0];
    var ranges = chart.getRanges();
    var dataRange = ranges.length > 0 ? ranges[0] : null;

    if (dataRange) {
      var data = dataRange.getValues();
      var min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
      var max = Number.MIN_VALUE;

      // Calculate min and max
      data.forEach(function (row) {
        row.forEach(function (cell) {
          if (typeof cell == 'number') {
            min = Math.min(min, cell);
            max = Math.max(max, cell);
          }
        });
      });

      // Calculate adjusted min and max values
      var adjustedMin = min - (0.1 * min);
      var adjustedMax = max + (0.1 * max);

      // Update chart values
      var newChart = chart.modify()
        .setOption('vAxis.minValue', adjustedMin)
        .setOption('vAxis.maxValue', adjustedMax)
        .build();

      sheet.updateChart(newChart);
    } else {
      Logger.log("No data range found for the chart.");
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log("No charts found on the sheet.");
  }
}
```

I have tried every fix I can find online, including ensuring that all permissions are available, that the project is linked to the spreadsheet, and even creating a whole new spreadsheet.
Regardless of what I try, the same error persists with no change.

Comment: I ran the code on a chart I just made up and I didn't have any problem.